# Exclusion of the URL scheme in front of a URL

Tags: javascript, html, protocols

Recently I've seen these kinds of URLs in CDN documents:

```
//cloudflare.cdnjs.com/foo
```

And I realised that they lacked the `http:` or `https:` in front of them.

Hmm, I thought, and tried implementing them in a local test, and realised that they didn't work (they resolved `//` to be `file://`, though it was supposed to be `http:`).

Then when I uploaded this to my testing server, it worked (resolved `//` to be `http://`).

So I was wondering, why would anybody write it without the protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: Leaving it at `//` will select either `http` or `https` depending on what the page is using. I ran into a problem with firefox not using my google fonts (if I remember right) on a page because I specified `http` and the page was a `https`. It is a security thing. So it is best to leave at `//`.

Comment: SO also has an own tag about it: [tag:protocol-relative]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Technically, it's not the "protocol", but the URI scheme)

For HTTP, excluding the scheme means that the UA will use the current scheme (and therefore protocol) to retrieve the file, which means some copy + pasted code can be re-used for both HTTP and HTTPS (or even SPDY) requests without triggering the "Partially secure page" warnings in browsers.

Comment: So this explains why when you're editing a local file and testing in a browser `//cloudflare.cdnjs.com/foo` gets resolved to `file://cloudflare.cdnjs.com/foo`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the user's security settings, browsers will often present a warning if a page serves up mixed content (both HTTP and HTTPS). Of course, you *could* just code your HTML using the same protocol that you intend the page to be hosted with. However, it's not uncommon to use the same HTML in both secure and non-secure portals. Furthermore, you'd really prefer your HTML to be agnostic to the underlying protocol.

Writing CDN links like this makes sure that the CDN request uses the same protocol as the host page.